# Saving an input value into a variable as you type, or as soon as the input loses focus

Tags: javascript, input, var

I've been working on this issue for a while now, and every solution I've come up with "almost works."  Ideally, I want to save the input value into the variable as I'm typing, so I don't have to perform any commands before the input value is saved into the variable.  Since I couldn't quite find the solution for that, I've been working on having it change as soon as the input loses focus.  I've tried .focusout, .change, and .blur, but none are actually changing it the moment the input loses focus.

```
//This will save the input value into the variable formInput
var formInput = $("#someForm input[type=text]").val();

//This successfully changes the value of formInput, but only after performing 
//another command, such as clicking go or pressing enter.  
//Tab does not count to the input "losing focus"

$("#someForm input[type=text]").focusout(function() {
$(this).val() = formInput.val();
});

// Same as focusout, as well as blur.
$("#someForm input[type=text]").change(function() {
$(this).val() = formInput.val();
});

//Nope.
$("#someForm input[type=text]").keyup(function() {
    formInput = $("this").val();
});
```

Comment: Do you want `$(this).val(formInput.val());` ? But this would replace what you just typed.

Comment: I really don't get your goal. You're trying to replace the value of the input by itself ?

Comment: @dystroy I'm trying to save the value of the input into the variable formInput, either as its being typed (dynamically saving it) or as soon as the cursor is no longer in the input field (which for some reason does not seem to be the way focusout works..)  

Later, the exact text from the input is being placed into a URL as a search term.  The trouble is that the variable is not being saved until I perform some kind of command inbetween, such as pressing the "Go" button that comes with the form, or pressing enter after typing it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In modern browsers, [listen to the `input` event](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/3kTYt/):

```
$("#someForm input[type=text]").on("input", function() {    
    formInput = $(this).val();
});
```

But the `keyup` handler should also work if you clear up your confusion about whether `formInput` is a string value containing the value of the field or a jQuery object linked to the field itself (if `formInput` is a string, it won't have a `val()` method).

Also this code:

```
$("this")
```

Is selecting all `<this>` elements, I'd be surprised if that returns anything.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the $(this) vs $("this"), I'll be working more with your code soon, so far I've had no luck.  Thanks again for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var inputText;
$("#someForm input[type=text]").keyup(function() {
    inputText = $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer.  This answer actually leaves my variable undefined.